# Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngtoolds2'

Tags: android, node.js, angular, ionic3

i'm getting the following error

> ```
> ionic-app-script task: 'build'
> Error: cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngtoolds2'
> ```

can anyone help me with this problem in angular?

Comment: It probably would be helpful if you provide some information. Like what you do to get this error, what you've changed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no module called @angular/compiler-cli/ngtoolds2.

It should be angular-cli-tools what you are looking for .

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-tools